# How to test that a method generating random numbers does generate random numbers

Tags: perl, unit-testing, testing

How can I test that a method generating random numbers actually generates random numbers? Is there some `($tested_method, rand)` sort of syntax?

Specifically, I'm referring to this ping generator method:

```perl
sub _create_ping_number {
   my ( $ping, @random_array );
   my $MAX            = 100000;
   my $random_counter = 0;

   if ( $random_counter == $MAX ) {
     @random_array   = ();
     $random_counter = 0;
   }

   until ( !undef( $random_array[ $ping = int( rand($MAX) ) ] ) ) { }
      $random_array[$ping] = 1;
      $random_counter++;
      return $ping;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to shoot your question down but there seems to be irony in it saying testing if something is random or not.  What makes you doubt this?

Comment: @squiguy yeah well actually im more or less sure its ok but so far i have been putting test for each of the methods i have used and if i left this one without any sort of test it would be a shame ... 99% of the system tested.......... T.T

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness for an introduction to this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links in comment by mob provide much detail on how difficult it is to assert that a data source is random.

For your unit test, you may be better off using `srand` in the test setup (making this technically a "white box" test), and relying on the fact that behaviour of `rand()` is well known. This is normal practice as far as I know, unless you want to test a PRNG or entropy source that you have written.